# Ubuntu 21.10 upgrade throwing an error

Tags: upgrade

**Setup**: I have installed Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.40 on my Windows 11 host. Running an Ubuntu 21.10 VM.

Since, Ubuntu 21.10 has reached EOL, I have tried to upgrade it referring to [Upgrade Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start). I am getting the following error. What would be the reason?

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Looks like networking issue?

Comment: 21.10 is now EOL https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: Thanks @24601, I am upgrading as it reached EOL.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. The post helped me to understand the reason for getting the error message. I see, the resolution given by the community was quite lengthy. Most of them talked about updating the system file /etc/apt/sources.list. May be that was the case with the older Ubuntu versions. I could upgrade my Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 using the GUI program "Software Updater" in a simpler way.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: When a release goes EOL it's archives are *moved* to old-releases. The instructions tell you how to deal with this, so you can fully upgrade & then *release-upgrade* to the next release. Yes it's more complex when you're using a release where the next-release is also EOL (*making yours easier given 22.04 was a LTS & isn't EOL) with the instructions covering all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 using the GUI program "Software Updater" in a **simpler way** without manually updating any of the system file as suggested in the post [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)